# replacing diode array with discrete components

Tags: diodes

I have a little proyect where I will be using a SIM908 GSM module. in the SIM908 Hardware Guide it states that a diode array should be used to protect the SIM lines, recomending an ESDA6V1W5 ([datasheet](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/stmicroelectronics/6548.pdf)) or SMF05C ([datasheet](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/42602/SEMTECH/SMF05C.html)). the problem is those have a very small SMD footprint; I will probably try to use one of them on the final board, but was thinking if I could replace it with discrete PTH diodes for the prototype? and if so, what kind of diodes should i look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not simple diodes, these are special (TVS), high peak current "Zener" (actually,avalanche) diodes. You need to check the parameters,such as breakdown voltage, maximum power dissipation etc. I found something (www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn75240.pdf), but you'll need to double check the parameters.

Comment: Also extremely important for data lines is the capacitance of the TVS device.  ON Semi makes low capacitance small discrete TVS devices. (Or ESD diodes as they are sometimes called.)